# Meaning of ?= and ??= in bitbake/yocto

Tags: embedded, yocto, bitbake

What does the different assignment types mean in bitbake recipe scripts, such as:

```
 BB_NUMBER_THREADS  ?=  "${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
 PARALLEL_MAKE  ?=  "-j ${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
 MACHINE    ??= "qemux86"
```

What of above is analogous to Ruby's `bb_number_threads ||= 'something'`?

Comment: That's not shell script, as far as I know, anyway. PHP?

Answer (score 15):

As per [this](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#setting-a-default-value) section of Bitbake manual

**?= is:**

> You can use the "?=" operator to achieve a "softer" assignment for a variable. This type of assignment allows you to define a variable if it is undefined when the statement is parsed, but to leave the value alone if the variable has a value. Here is an example:

`A ?= "aval"`

> If A is set at the time this statement is parsed, the variable retains its value. However, if A is not set, the variable is set to "aval".

**??= is:**

> It is possible to use a "weaker" assignment than in the previous section by using the "??=" operator. This assignment behaves identical to "?=" except that the assignment is made at the end of the parsing process rather than immediately. Consequently, when multiple "??=" assignments exist, the last one is used. Also, any "=" or "?=" assignment will override the value set with "??=". Here is an example:

```
 A ??= "somevalue"
 A ??= "someothervalue"
```

> If A is set before the above statements are parsed, the variable
>   retains its value. If A is not set, the variable is set to
>   "someothervalue".
>
> Again, this assignment is a "lazy" or "weak" assignment because it
>   does not occur until the end of the parsing process.

Answer (score 1):

Short and crisp explaination would be:

IF A is not set before and

`A ?= aval
 A ?= difval`

at the end of the parsing, the value of `A` will be `aval`.

Simple rule about `?=` : The first set value will be used.

---

IF A is not set before and

`A ?= aval
 A ??= difval`

OR

`A = aval
 A ??= difval`

at the end of the parsing, the value of A will stay `aval`

Simple rule about `??=`: `=` & `?=` overwrite `??=`

---

IF A is not set before and

`A ??= aval
 A ??= difval`

at the end of the parsing, the value of A will be `difval`

Simple rule about `??=`: last set value by `??=` will be considered.

Comment: Thank you. Other explanations are always hard to parse into real use cases.